# JSONP Data is undefined with cross domain posting

Tags: jquery, .net, json, web-services, jsonp

I am trying to send a request from jquery $.ajax method to a .net web service I have created on a different domain. I have tried a number of things yet I still cannot get it too work. The response I keep getting is undefined.

Can anyone advise please?

Thanks

.NET Code

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string callback = "";
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["callback"]))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["var1"]))
                        SaveData(context.Request["var1"]);
                    callback = context.Request["callback"];


                    var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();                    
                    string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(JSON);

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    string qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"];

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(callback+"(\"Clients : \"" + sJSON+ ")");


                }

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

                context.Response.Write(callback +
            "({ \"return\": \"" + exc.Message + "\" })");
            }
        }
```

JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
                url:        "URL",
                dataType:   "jsonp",
                success:    function(data){
                    alert(data); // Always Undefined


                }
            });
```

Comment: What is that `\"Clients : \"` bit doing there?

Comment: Thats the object type of the list as its past into json. It seems to be undefined regardless of the \"Clients : \" bit

Comment: No, it's not. There is no such thing as an "object type", and from what I can see you're generating invalid JavaScript (`foo("Clients : "{ })`). What happens if you remove `\"Clients : \"`?

Comment: It still appears as undefined. I am getting a response back as the success condition is being run yet I can see no data in FireBug

Comment: What's the `JSON` variable you are passing to the serializer? Where is it coming from and most importantly why is it called JSON? I mean the purpose of the serializer is to pass an object instance and to produce JSON. I hope you are not passing JSON string to it.

Comment: No I am not passing JSON to it. It is a method call which returns a List of type Client. I just removed it when I posted it here to remove bloat.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning broken JSON here:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(callback+"(\"Clients : \"" + sJSON+ ")");
```

Do you notice the `\"` after `Clients:`? You should have placed it before the `:`. So your JSON looks like this (if you had used a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug you would immediately have noticed that as FireBug would have written this error to your console):

```
callback("Clients : "[{"ID":1,"Name":"client 1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"client 2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"client 3"}])
```

See the problem?

**Never** hardcode JSON. **Never** use string concatenations to build JSON. **Never**.

**Always** use JSON serializer when building or parsing JSON.

Just like that:

```
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(new { Clients = JSON });
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, sJSON));
```

In this example I am passing an anonymous type `new { Clients = JSON }` to the JSON serializer which will take care to produce the correct and valid output:

```
callback("Clients":[{"ID":1,"Name":"client 1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"client 2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"client 3"}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do see the formatting issue so thanks for that. However I still seem to be getting the undefined issue with this string Data = oSerializer.Serialize(new { Clients = JSON });
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, Data));

JSON is a list that I am passing it. Thanks again